# Integrate Audio and Filter Method

Tags: c#, naudio, lowpass-filter

Hi I have an Audio track which i want to play after passing it through a low pass filter. I am using NAudio's BiQuadFilter class for the filter part. It has an Inbuilt method for it. The first parameter is sample rate, second is the cutoff frequency and third is Quality factor Q. I am not being able to integrate the Filter method with my audio part.
Here is my code:

```
        var r = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, 1500, 1);
        var reader = new WaveFileReader(File.OpenRead(@"D:1.wav"));
        var waveOut=new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();
```

I Managed to finally get it working. Don't know if it's correct. Here's what I did:

```
    public MyFilter(ISampleProvider sourceProvider,int cutOffFreq)
    {
        this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
        this.cutOffFreq = cutOffFreq;

        channels = sourceProvider.WaveFormat.Channels;
        filters = new BiQuadFilter[channels];
        CreateFilters();
    }

    private void CreateFilters()
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < channels; n++)
            if (filters[n] == null)
                filters[n] = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
            else
                filters[n].SetLowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return sourceProvider.WaveFormat; } }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
            buffer[offset + i] = filters[(i % channels)].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);

        return samplesRead;
    }
```

is this correct?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you want to achieve, what did you try, why did it not meet your expectations?

Comment: I want to filter my audio using low pass filter. How do I do that?
How will the BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter method know which audio is supposed to be used as input? Here the result of LowPassFilter is stored in 'r' and reader is object of WaveFileReader which stores which track to play. How do i integrate the effects of Low Pass Filter with my audio such that only frequency below 1500 Hz is played?

Comment: Your code looks good! I don't find any mistake. I am just curious how you managed that byte/float problem. I suppose your class doesn't implement the `NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider` interface...

Comment: No. My class implements ISampleProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BiQuadFilter` has a method `Transform(float[] inBuffer, float[] outBuffer)` which might work out for you. To do the conversion I would create an `IWaveProvider` which calls the method.

An `IWaveProvider` is a class which provides audio data. I recommend to set the source of the audio data in the constructor:

```
public class MyWaveProvider : NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider
{
    private readonly NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider inWaveProvider;

    public MyWaveProvider(NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider inWaveProvider)
    {
        this.inWaveProvider = inWaveProvider;
        this.WaveFormat = inWaveProvider.WaveFormat;
    }

    public NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }

    public int Read(byte[] outBuffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return this.inWaveProvider.Read(outBuffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

You see in the `Read()` method that the bytes are read from the source and written into the destination buffer. At that point you can manipulate the data using BiQuadFilter.Transform(float[] inBuffer, float[] outBuffer). I leave the type inconsistency as an exercise for you. I really don't know.

When you pimped the `Read()` method to use your `BiQuadFilter.Transfrom()` method, you can call the following code:

```
var r = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, 1500, 1);
var reader = new WaveFileReader(File.OpenRead(@"D:1.wav"));
var filter = new MyWaveProvider(reader, r); // reader is the source for filter
var waveOut = new WaveOut();
waveOut.Init(filter); // filter is the source for waveOut
waveOut.Play();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Can you please Elaborate?

Comment: Thank you For That!
But the MyWaveProvider class has one parameter in it's constructor and while creating an object, we are passing two parameters :(
Also, if I simply use Transform Method, how will it apply effects of Low Pass Filter? :(

Comment: The `MyWaveProvider` class is an example for a minimum IWaveProvider. It does nothing. You must modify the `Read()` method to do what you want ("[...] manipulate the data [...]").

Comment: Can you please see whether the code which I posted above is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that derives from `ISampleProvider`, and then in the Read method, pass the samples from the source through the `BiQuadFilter` with the `Transform` method. As an example, have a look at the [source for the `Equalizer` class](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioWpfDemo/EqualizationDemo/Equalizer.cs) in the NAudio WPF Demo

Comment: Thank you, but I am a newbie at this and I am not being able to understand exactly what to do.

Comment: Any Suggestions @Mark Heath

Comment: The transform method returns float and SetLowPassFilter returns BiQuadFilter type. How do convert that to WAV file and play?